# CodeMirror on rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, codemirror

I am using rails 3.1 and I am facing a problem with attaching codemirror editor to my form textarea.

```
//----- code (application.js)------//
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#comment_body').each(function() {
         var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(this, {
             lineNumbers : true,
             matchBrackets : true
         });
     })
})
//------end------//
```

The problem is that the textarea becomes uneditable. Can you tell me the way to use this?

Comment: Please list your application.js and application.css.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the scripts and the css of codemirror in your application.js for the scripts and application.css for the stylesheets.

application.js should have this:

```
//=require codemirror
```

And your application.css should have:

```
/*
*= require codemirror
*/
```